# how to set lwuit textarea scrolling false

Tags: java-me, scroll, textarea, lwuit, midlet

I want to add large string content to a container dynamically.
There are 60 different contents(strings) to be displayed in this container.

To add the string to container, I am adding a TextArea(empty border with 100% transparency).

The problem is that TextArea offers scroll and I do not want it to scroll. Instead I want to grow(increase height) according to content. I am unable to achieve this.

Can you help me out with this?
Or can I use any other component for the purpose?

I am using LWUIT with J2ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive text area and return false for isScrollableY() although it should generally work seamlessly even if you don't do that (since your parent layout is scrollable). Is it possible you changed the text area and don't revalidate the parent form on the EDT?

There are problems with text area layout when it is modified by a separate thread (race condition with the layout code).

Answer (score 0):

First put the `TextArea.setSingleLineTextArea(false)` , and grow by content true.

Comment: I already have done it, It grows but start scrolling after screen size. I do not want it to scroll as its parent layout is desired to scroll.

Comment: i have set scrollable to false to all, except for the layout which is desired to scroll

Comment: can you describe your form? It's a Form with a LinearLayout and whats more?

Comment: my form have too many components, just to make it simple, i have a layout and two TextArea in it, instead TextAreas to scroll separately, i want them to grow, so that layout can provide scroll to combination